# Take Screenshot of UIImageView and UILabel then Share it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I think I'm near to solving the problem. I've a `UItableView` with a prototype cell which looks like this:
[image: Cell]

 The **gray-scale background image** you see is coming from server and the text is the **overlay text** which is a `UILabel` on it and will change on every image which is also in the server. So it's like **two layers** which I'm trying to send. Third red button is the button of share and say I select share this image in email this function will be called:

```
-(UIImage *)makeImageofCell:(NSUInteger)sender
{
    HomeCell *cellObj;
    cellObj.tag = sender;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cellObj.homeImg.frame.size );
    [cellObj.homeImg.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    [cellObj.overlayText.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

In `-(void)shareButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender` I've written the code of sharing. Now in this function I want to send that image. Here is what I'm doing: 
 `UIImage *imageToShare = [self makeImageofCell:sender.tag];` which is calling the `makeImageofCell` function and assigning it's value to a `UIImage`. So I'm writing this to share that URL.

```
NSString *imageToShare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey! Check out this Image %@",imageToShare];
```

But all I'm getting is `Image is: (null)`. Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please following code for the screen shot of UIWindow You just replace with you custom view or cell.

```
- (UIImage*)takeScreenshot
{
    // get the key-window references
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

    // manipulate boundries of key-window
    CGRect rect = [keyWindow bounds];

    // create context using size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);

    // get the context reference
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // render in context
    [keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];

    // get the rendered image
    UIImage *capturedScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // complete context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // return image
    return takeScreenshot;
}
```

**Edited**

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
         UIButton *btnShareImage = (UIButton*)[cell1 viewWithTag:KTAGABSENTBUTTON];
         [btnShareImage addTarget:self action:@selector(shareImageAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [btnShareImage setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li %li",(long)indexPath.section,(long)indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
         return cell;
     }
    -(void)shareImageAction:(UIButton*)sender{
        NSString *str=[sender titleForState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        NSArray *ar=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[ar objectAtIndex:1] intValue] inSection:[[ar objectAtIndex:0] intValue]];

        HomeCell *cellObj = (HomeCell*) [yourTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIImage *imageToShare = [self makeImageofCell:cellObj];

    }
    -(UIImage *)makeImageofCell:(HomeCell*)cellObj
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cellObj.homeImg.frame.size );
        [cellObj.homeImg.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        [cellObj.overlayText.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return viewImage;
    }
```

May this help to you.

Comment: `UITableView` is involved so I'm having trouble with the `tags` I think. The code of taking screenshot works just fine I've tested it before implementing in this project.

Comment: What is `KTAGABSENTBUTTON` this?

Comment: It's just for reference of the Cell button if you have that cell reference then you can use like wise UIButton *btnShareImage =cell.yourButtonVariableName.

Comment: So I used `viewWithTag:cellObj.shareBtn.tag` at the place of `KTAGABSENTBUTTON` but app always crash in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method at 2nd line `[btnShareImage addTarget:self action:@selector(shareImageAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` and this is the known error `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84995/discussion-between-nimit-parekh-and-talha-ch).